# I want to get anchor tag within an <li> tag if the <li> has active class

Tags: jquery

**HTML Code:**

```
<li role="tab" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" aria-selected="true"><a href="#ContentPlaceHolder1_C1Tab1_tabIntake" tabindex="-1">Intake</a></li>
```

I want to get intake text if `<li>` tag has `active` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean **ui-state-active** as active class then you can get text by this jquery command.

```
var text = $("li.ui-state-active a").text();
```

hope it helps